# Tk frame: how to deactivate internal handler for expose events?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to draw into a Tk 8.6 `frame` using Cairo C/X11 code. I found that I could prevent the frame from redrawing itself in case of Expose events (e.g. window size changes) by passing `-background ""` as option to the `frame` (so basically the `frame` doesn't know what to redraw). Two questions:

- Is there a better way to tell a `frame` to not redraw itself but to leave it to somebody else?
- Can I replace Tk's internal event handlers (for Expose etc.) by my own on the C level? (At the moment I'm doing it on the Tcl level by `bind $frame <Expose> "myExposeHandler..."`.)

Thanks for your help!

(The `-container yes` option seems to have no effect, btw.)

Comment: The `-container yes` is for integrating with the `-use` option on toplevels, allowing a toplevel _possibly in another process_ to be contained within a widget. It's definitely not what you want here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-background ""` option is the one which disables redraws of frames, and is typically used where you're going to hand off the XId of the frame as the handle to draw on to some other process. (This used to be how people would integrate video players; I don't know how practical that still is.) There's also the `-container true` option, as you found, but that's intended only for use where you're going to embed a toplevel from another Tk process inside the frame (it enables a special protocol for exchanging geometry manager information, IIRC) and isn't what you want here.

However, if you're already working with your own C code then you might as well make your own widget. Then you'll have complete control over all the event handling and can do anything you want. The usual place for people to start when doing this is with the [`square` widget in the Tk sources](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/artifact/90f33f1ffe882c56) (too long to include here). That demonstrates a lot of things about how Tk does event handling, such as postponing of updates until “idle” (i.e., effectively event coalescing) and handling Tk's configuration system. The key things are that you define a widget record that has all the configurable fields *and anything else you need to make the widget work* in it (see the `Square` typedef), a list of option specifications that describe what bits are to be configured and what the defaults are (see the `optionSpecs` static declaration), a constructor command (`SquareObjCmd`), an instance command (`SquareWidgetObjCmd`), an event handler (`SquareObjEventProc`), and a drawing callback (`SquareDisplay`). There's other bits too, like how to delete things and so on, but I'm sure you'll get the hang of those. Then all you have to do is register the constructor command as normal for Tcl commands; it's the usual for any code that extends Tcl/Tk.

Doing it this way is a bit more work, but it will make a much more robust binding between your real code and Tcl. It's up to you to decide how much complexity you put in the instance command; Tk's own widgets vary from the very simple (the `messagebox` widget is only slightly more complicated than the `square` example widget) to the hugely complicated (both the `canvas` and the `text` are really complicated pieces of code).